# Difficulties in reading Uml diagram syntax

Tags: uml

I having problem in reading the syntax in uml diagram:

```
malls:string[*]
```

What is the string indicate? How do I write that in variable declaration in C++?

Comment: maybe is double column u have any idea about my question?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the line you mentioned is actually part of a class deifinition?
In that case it is an attribute definition where

- `malls` is the name of the attribute
- `string` is the type of the attribute
- `[*]` is the multiplicity of the attribute. In this case the single `*` is actually short for `[0..*]` which means that there will be zero or more strings stored in the attribute malls.

There are many ways to implement something like that in code, including using an array of strings, or a list of some kind.

Comment: sorry i dont get what u mean, please explain further,do i need array or what?